# Rselenium can not click all radiobutton (only some of them)

Tags: javascript, r, selenium, web-scraping, rselenium

I am trying to get some scraping skills with `RSelenium` and I am confronted to a difficulty.

I want to choose languages for the comments in this [page](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g187438-d12718258-Reviews-Prohobitox-Malaga_Costa_del_Sol_Province_of_Malaga_Andalucia.html). But when the popup radio button list appear, I manage to click some of them and not the others. I thing I did get the elements properly though. Here is what I tried:

```
library(RSelenium)

remDr <- remoteDriver(
  remoteServerAddr = "localhost",
  port = 4445L,
  browserName = "firefox"
)

url <- "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g187438-d12718258-Reviews-Prohobitox-Malaga_Costa_del_Sol_Province_of_Malaga_Andalucia.html"

remDr$navigate(url)

# click more language popup
webElems <- remDr$findElements(using = "css selector", ".taLnk") # taLnk is for dropdown like
webElemstext <- unlist(lapply(webElems, function(x) {x$getElementText()}))
webElems[[which(webElemstext == "More languages")]]$clickElement()
```

[image]

I try to get the radio buttons this way:

```
langues <- remDr$findElements(using = "class", "ui_radio")
langues_txt <-  unlist(lapply(langues, function(x) {x$getElementText()}))

> langues_txt
 [1] "All languages"  "English (120)"  "Spanish (66)"   "Norwegian (25)" "All languages" 
 [6] "English (120)"  "Spanish (66)"   "Norwegian (25)" "Dutch (22)"     "Swedish (13)"  
[11] "French (12)"    "German (10)"    "Italian (7)"    "Danish (3)"     "Finnish (2)"   
[16] "Portuguese (1)"
```

The weird thing is that I can click the last radiobutton, but not the others, and I don't get it. If I do try to click finnish:

```
langues[[14]]$clickElement() 
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE)
```

[image]

nothing happend. But with Portuguese:

```
langues[[16]]$clickElement() 
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE)
```

[image]

Here it worked. 
I don't see any difference between the two situations, so I don't find a solution to click any radio button in the popup.

Any ideas?

## edit

I tried to click all of them. I can click "All language", "English", "Norwegian", and "Portuguese". None of the others work, even with the proposed solution:

### BigDataScientist solution

I did load the popup menu, and I deleted the cookies before:

```
remDr$deleteAllCookies()
remDr$navigate(url)

# click more language
webElems <- remDr$findElements(using = "css selector", ".taLnk") # taLnk est le css pour etendre des menus.
webElemstext <- unlist(lapply(webElems, function(x) {x$getElementText()}))
webElems[[which(webElemstext == "More languages")]]$clickElement()
```

Here is the solution given

```
langues <- remDr$findElements(
  using = "xpath", 
  value = "/html/body/div/div/div/div[@class = 'ui_radio item']"
)
langues_txt <-  unlist(lapply(langues, function(x) {x$getElementText()}))
langues[[8]]$clickElement() # It should be german
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE)
```

here is the result:

[image]

Indeed here I get only 12 languages, but I am still unable to click on the buttons I want.

### supputuri solution

It doesn't work for me either: I tried both:

```
langElement <- remDr$findElement(using = "css", ".more-options .ui_radio.item:nth-of-type(8) input")
langElement$clickElement()
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE)
```

and

```
langElement <- remDr$findElement(using = "css", ".more-options div[data-tracker='German'] input")
# click on language radio button
langElement$clickElement()
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE)
```

none worked:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The radio button doesn't receive the click event when the name is not long enough within the clicked container.

When an element is clicked, the driver sends all the events to the element present at the top at the center of the provided element.

But in your case and for most of the elements, the center point of the container is the container itself and not the expected radio button.

If you want to reliably click the radio button, then click the `<label>` instead :

```
item <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', "[data-tracker='German'] label")
item$clickElement()
```

Or by text with an XPath:

```
item <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', '//label[contains(.,"German")]')
item$clickElement()
```

Comment: wha !! This seems to make sense. Does it depend on screen resolution (and so it is the reason why BigDataScientist and suputuri could not reproduce my error ? I am using 3200 x 1800 px). I will try that in few moments, but thank you for the input

Comment: @denis, I didn't check if the resolution has an impact on the width, but in any case it won't affect the click if it's performed on the  `<label>`.

Comment: yep, that is it!

Answer (score 3):

**Root of the problem:**

With the class selector being used, you also capture the potential language settings for the tablet version (?) of the homepage. Look at the following screenshot:

In the first line you see the class `choice is-shown-at-tablet`.
[image]

**A solution:**

You should be able to avoid the problem by modifying your selector (and exclude the tablet option). One way would be to use the full xpath (as it differs from the xpath of the tablet options).

The xpath would be:

`/html/body/div/div/div/div[@class = 'ui_radio item']`

**A test:**

Starting with your code for reproducibility:

```
url <- "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g187438-d12718258-Reviews-Prohobitox-Malaga_Costa_del_Sol_Province_of_Malaga_Andalucia.html"

remDr$navigate(url)
# click more language popup
webElems <- remDr$findElements(using = "css selector", ".taLnk") # taLnk is for dropdown like
webElemstext <- unlist(lapply(webElems, function(x) {x$getElementText()}))
webElems[[which(webElemstext == "More languages")]]$clickElement()
```

And then find the elements with the new selector:

```
langues <- remDr$findElements(
  using = "xpath", 
  value = "/html/body/div/div/div/div[@class = 'ui_radio item']"
)

langues_txt <-  unlist(lapply(langues, function(x) {x$getElementText()}))
> langues_txt
[1] "All languages"  "English (120)"  "Spanish (67)"   "Norwegian (25)" "Dutch (22)"     "Swedish (13)"  
[7] "French (12)"    "German (10)"    "Italian (7)"    "Danish (3)"     "Finnish (2)"    "Portuguese (1)"
```

As you see you go down from 16 to 12 language options (excluding the doubles) and getting only the one you see in the screenshot.

You can test clicking them (e.g. for German):

```
langues[[8]]$clickElement()
```

**Note:**

Probably you know it already, but for sake of completeness: If you want to test multiple languages and clicked one already, you have to bring up the language popup "up" again, by running the code section after my comment "Starting with your code for reproducibility:".

**Edit:**

Unfortunately, I can´t reproduce your error. Could you maybe try this:

```
langues <- remDr$findElements(
  using = "xpath", 
  value = "/html/body/div/div/div/div[@class = 'ui_radio item']/label[contains(text(), 'German')]"
)[[1]]$clickElement()
```

or

```
langues <- remDr$findElements(
      using = "xpath", 
      value = "/html/body/div/div/div/div[@class = 'ui_radio item']/label[contains(text(), 'German')]"
    )
remDr$executeScript("arguments[0].click();", args = langues[1])
```

Comment: Thanks! I will test that tomorrow, but it looks like it is exactly what I needed. What is the best way to know the full xpath ? The Element inspector of firefox (or the page source) ? Is there something like gadgetSelector for the xpath ?

Comment: nope, I am sorry, but I still get the same problem here, I only can click few of them, most of them don't work.

Comment: Could you give a screenshot output after the `clickElement` ? see mine in the edits of my question

Comment: sry i didnt have internet for two days. Unfortunately i cant reproduce the error. I see German comments only, after running the code. I made an edit at the end of my post. Maybe we could try quering the element directly and clicking it.

Comment: Yes the last edit worked. Indeed, it must use the label, and not the input. I gave the bounty to Florent B, who found the answer a bit before, and the explanation. But many thanks for all the inputs

Answer (score 1):

Let me keep the things simple and straight.

I would suggest selecting the language by using the below css.

**Option 1: Using CSS with Language**

```
.more-options div[data-tracker='Finnish'] input
```

Here is the script.

```
# find element using css
langElement <- remDr$findElement(using = "css", ".more-options div[data-tracker='XXXchangeLangHereXXX'] input")
# click on language radio button
langElement$clickElement()
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

**Option 2: Using CSS based on index**

If you want to select the language by index (I believe that's not you are looking for though) you can use the below approach.

```
# this css will get `Finnish` radio button
.more-options .ui_radio.item:nth-of-type(11) input
```

Here is the script

```
# find element using css
langElement <- remDr$findElement(using = "css", ".more-options .ui_radio.item:nth-of-type(XXXChangeIndexHereXXX) input")
# click on language radio button
langElement$clickElement()
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you give a bit of explanation for the `.more-options` par of your css ? I am not sure to understand it properly. Addtionally, could you tell me what is the advantage compared to BigDataScientist answer (i.e. using xpath) ? Don't you have the possibility with your solution to encounter the same kind of problem I was facing, i.e. obtaining other language setting than the one I was trying to get ?

Comment: Did you actually managed to have the radiobutton selected ? Could you give a screenshot after the `clickElement()` ? I don't manage to get it work

Comment: I don't have the ruby selenium on machine, but was able to select the radio buttons successfully using the css that I posted. Added screenshots for your reference.

Comment: hmm.  You try js click rather `clickElement()`, which should make the difference.