# RSelenium -> click checkbox files

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, rselenium

Basically, I would like to automatically download multiple files at once from a webpage ->> http://alertario.rio.rj.gov.br/download/dados-pluviometricos/

I am currently following the tutorials from: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BK_JBk_l5uQ; also here:https://github.com/ggSamoora/TutorialsBySamoora/blob/main/R_downloader_Tutorial.R

BUT, to download it, I need to specify (select) a few fields beforehand. Check image bellow.
[image]

May someone help me with automating that?

My current stage:

```
#install.packages("RSelenium")
#install.packages("netstat")
#install.packages("binman")

# load the necessary packages
library(tidyverse)
library(RSelenium)
library(netstat)

binman::list_versions("geckodriver")
# "0.32.1" "0.32.2" "0.33.0"

# connecting to selenium server
rs_driver_object <- rsDriver(browser = 'firefox',
                             port = free_port())

# access the client object
remDr <- rs_driver_object$client

# open a web browser
remDr$open()

# navigate to the website containing the database
remDr$navigate("http://alertario.rio.rj.gov.br/download/dados-pluviometricos/")
```

I am expecting to download all the data available from this page for a research project.

Comment: Similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56894525/rselenium-can-not-click-all-radiobutton-only-some-of-them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular problem doesn't actually require RSelenium, so if you're open to a more typical approach then this answer might work for you. The website uses POST requests to pull down the data as a zip file, so all we need to do is make our own POST request. I prefer the `httr` package for this but you could use whichever one you'd like.

We get the information we need (body and headers) from submitting a single request manually and using Chrome's devtools to see what the request consisted of:

[image]

In this case, the important information is the request URL

`http://websempre.rio.rj.gov.br/dados/pluviometricos/plv/`

the request headers

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 949
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie: _ga=GA1.4.856843378.1683144629; _gid=GA1.4.1868063308.1683144629; BIGipServer~interno~pool_websempre_http=rd1o00000000000000000000ffff0a02df72o80; _gat=1; TS01a4bab6=01a427213d9189188aaff0fbe3a73727c18f2fc4dc5b10c78d93f8867a481703e3840be508d0f33440460c6f7de39c5d1e4e830651541ff39ba0a1913d3ce11fc2a21fb05d; TS97dc297c027=087c8a1c25ab2000cfabcd20d6f9ccacc7398aab844381c3d40417e34a9d0935ff715cc2f2b63ac208608fab44113000be24740de9c4c96989c4111d3b3ee12ea1b6b438e414a7536af359832b14805819bed161727885be6f511f76c8015cd3
DNT: 1
Host: websempre.rio.rj.gov.br
Origin: http://websempre.rio.rj.gov.br
Referer: http://websempre.rio.rj.gov.br/dados/pluviometricos/plv/
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

and the request body (from the "Payload" tab)

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken=t0QnQFV4xRrh3eXmIHaxGRAXCDeDBM7F&1-check=on&1-choice=1997&2-check=on&2-choice=1997&3-check=on&3-choice=1997&4-check=on&4-choice=1997&5-check=on&5-choice=1997&6-check=on&6-choice=1997&7-check=on&7-choice=1997&8-check=on&8-choice=1997&9-check=on&9-choice=1997&10-check=on&10-choice=1997&11-check=on&11-choice=1997&12-check=on&12-choice=1997&13-check=on&13-choice=1997&14-check=on&14-choice=1997&15-check=on&15-choice=1997&16-check=on&16-choice=1997&17-check=on&17-choice=1997&18-check=on&18-choice=1997&19-check=on&19-choice=1997&20-check=on&20-choice=1997&21-check=on&21-choice=1997&22-check=on&22-choice=1997&23-check=on&23-choice=1997&24-check=on&24-choice=1997&25-check=on&25-choice=1997&26-check=on&26-choice=1997&27-check=on&27-choice=1997&28-check=on&28-choice=1997&29-check=on&29-choice=1997&30-check=on&30-choice=1997&31-check=on&31-choice=1997&32-check=on&32-choice=1997&33-check=on&33-choice=1997&all-chek=on&choice=1997
```

All we need to do now is code those up in an R-friendly way. We need the request body to be a named character vector so we use `strsplit`, `separate`, and `pull` (last two from the `tidyr` and `dplyr` packages, respectively):

```
chromebody <- "csrfmiddlewaretoken=pZOjhFqzBVeajAXAWhuNOctqSJ1GU04t&1-check=on&1-choice=1997&2-check=on&2-choice=1997&3-check=on&3-choice=1997&4-check=on&4-choice=1997&5-check=on&5-choice=1997&6-check=on&6-choice=1997&7-check=on&7-choice=1997&8-check=on&8-choice=1997&9-check=on&9-choice=1997&10-check=on&10-choice=1997&11-check=on&11-choice=1997&12-check=on&12-choice=1997&13-check=on&13-choice=1997&14-check=on&14-choice=1997&15-check=on&15-choice=1997&16-check=on&16-choice=1997&17-check=on&17-choice=1997&18-check=on&18-choice=1997&19-check=on&19-choice=1997&20-check=on&20-choice=1997&21-check=on&21-choice=1997&22-check=on&22-choice=1997&23-check=on&23-choice=1997&24-check=on&24-choice=1997&25-check=on&25-choice=1997&26-check=on&26-choice=1997&27-check=on&27-choice=1997&28-check=on&28-choice=1997&29-check=on&29-choice=1997&30-check=on&30-choice=1997&31-check=on&31-choice=1997&32-check=on&32-choice=1997&33-check=on&33-choice=1997&all-chek=on&choice=1997"
body <- strsplit(chromebody, "&")[[1]] %>%
  data.frame(init=.) %>%
  separate(init, into = c("name", "value"), sep = "=") %>%
  pull(value, name) %>%
  as.list()
```

The middleware token here also seems to change with each request, so you'll probably have to sub in one of your own.

Then add the necessary headers as a named list:

```
heads <- add_headers(c(
  Accept="text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7",
  `Accept-Encoding`="gzip, deflate",
  `Accept-Language`="en-US,en;q=0.9",
  `Cache-Control`="max-age=0",
  Connection="keep-alive",
  # `Content-Length`="561",
  # `Content-Type`="application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  Cookie="_ga=GA1.4.856843378.1683144629; _gid=GA1.4.1868063308.1683144629; _gat=1; BIGipServer~interno~pool_websempre_http=rd1o00000000000000000000ffff0a02df72o80; TS01a4bab6=01a427213d59269d7c5c5786c4e31eb85e255c954942cbdc35eef8018262ac13b6852857ef0c654e412681b104aa44a4962091e7352e34338e28f74cd80e4856cf86705e54; TS97dc297c027=087c8a1c25ab2000d80e586f48bcd94dd8b861f67ab2f6791bcc83cfd93a01b01d36fddcc19b973a08ae4bf3f211300008ca4399aa2b8c0ad52ff748804cba793ea0af1daa5e9b0b374cba61997313ecab8ca3cd8268dd0a9172e0dc4788c29e",
  Host="websempre.rio.rj.gov.br",
  Origin="http://websempre.rio.rj.gov.br",
  Referer="http://websempre.rio.rj.gov.br/dados/pluviometricos/plv/",
  `User-Agent`="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
))
```

I commented out the Content Length and Content Type because they were causing issues but everything else is basically verbatim from the devtools taskbar. The cookie here may also change - you'll likely have to sub in your own values after submitting a request of your own.

Then, all we need to do is make the POST request with the arguments. Here I use the write_disk() because I couldn't figure out how to unencode/unzip while staying in memory. Here I just write the files out to my Downloads folder but you'll likely want to change the path to your working directory.

```
post_response <- POST(base_url, body = body, config = heads, write_disk(path = "~/../Downloads/tempfile.zip", overwrite = TRUE))
```

However, note that this only pulls down files for a single year. You'll have to write a quick loop to pull down the files from every year by replacing the "1997" in the current request body with 1998, 1999, etc.

Finally, note that you're hitting their server with a lot of requests for this data, so please be mindful of the request rate.

Answer (score 0):

MANY THANKS for this help. I was able to progress in the suggestions you made and create a loop to run over the years. I will do pieces by pieces in order to not make their serves busy or mad. Therefore, the example loop will run only 2000-2005.

Here it goes if someone is interested:

```
library(dplyr)
library(httr)

# Create the base URL and body for the POST request
base_url <- "http://websempre.rio.rj.gov.br/dados/pluviometricos/plv/"
chromebody <- paste0("csrfmiddlewaretoken=pZOjhFqzBVeajAXAWhuNOctqSJ1GU04t&", paste0(rep(seq(1:33), length(years)), "-check=on&", paste0(rep(seq(1:33), length(years)), "-choice=", years, collapse = "&"), collapse = "&"))

# Create headers for the request
heads <- add_headers(c(
  Accept="text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7",
  `Accept-Encoding`="gzip, deflate",
  `Accept-Language`="en-US,en;q=0.9",
  `Cache-Control`="max-age=0",
  Connection="keep-alive",
  Cookie="_ga=GA1.4.856843378.1683144629; _gid=GA1.4.1868063308.1683144629; _gat=1; BIGipServer~interno~pool_websempre_http=rd1o00000000000000000000ffff0a02df72o80; TS01a4bab6=01a427213d59269d7c5c5786c4e31eb85e255c954942cbdc35eef8018262ac13b6852857ef0c654e412681b104aa44a4962091e7352e34338e28f74cd80e4856cf86705e54; TS97dc297c027=087c8a1c25ab2001d80e586f48bcd94dd8b861f67ab2f6791bcc83cfd93a01b01d36fddcc19b973a08ae4bf3f211300008ca4399aa2b8c0ad52ff748804cba793ea0af1daa5e9b0b374cba62001313ecab8ca3cd8268dd0a9172e0dc4788c29e",
  Host="websempre.rio.rj.gov.br",
  Origin="http://websempre.rio.rj.gov.br",
  Referer="http://websempre.rio.rj.gov.br/dados/pluviometricos/plv/",
  `User-Agent`="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
))

# Loop through the years and download the data
for (year in 2000:2005) {
  # Update the body with the current year
  body <- strsplit(chromebody, "&")[[1]] %>%
    data.frame(init=.) %>%
    tidyr::separate(init, into = c("name", "value"), sep = "=") %>%
    mutate(value = ifelse(name == "1-choice", year, value)) %>%
    pull(value, name) %>%
    as.list()
  
  # Update the file name with the current year
  file_name <- paste0("D:/data_", year, ".zip")
  
  # Download the data for the current year
  post_response <- httr::POST(base_url, body = body, config = heads, httr::write_disk(path = file_name, overwrite = TRUE))
  
  # Print a message to indicate which year was downloaded
  cat("Data for year", year, "downloaded.\n")
}
```